# SIGSEGV Error when allocating large array

Tags: java, android, arrays, segmentation-fault

I want to allocate a float array with large size:

```
float AudioData[] = new float[numSamples];
```

but I get this error in android studio:

```
SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0xc))
```

I know it is because stack overflow and I have to move array somewhere else.

The question is how can I move array to heap? Generally how to deal with it?

Comment: how big is `numSamples`?

Comment: are you sure it is a stack fault?

Comment: `numSamples` is 18000000 in this case. It works flawlessly with smaller numbers .

Comment: a large object allocation would raise an out of memory java error instead of an operating system SIGSEGV. Your problem probably lies somewhere else